# How to add to Sharepoint list editing mode false after value change

Tags: development, list, list-view

I have got a list with a lot of elements. I want to add to sharepoint list date which block editing when the date expired. When the date not equal the selected Value.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Can you explain further?

Comment: I want to block editing and deleting elements from Custom list when the some date expired.